# RSS Reader for iphone rejected ! need a solution

Tags: iphone

after submitting the application twice till now it has been rejected for nearly the same reason ! 
First time it was rejected because the application freezes till the RSS loads and i solved it by moving the parsing process to sub queue and added an activity indicator.
Second time it was rejected for "screen displays an activity indicator indefinitely and no content is loaded".
The problem is the indicator won't disappear till the RSS loads ! which mainly depend on the internet connection and the parsing delay time "NSXMLParser library in my case" ! any help with that ?!

Comment: StackOverflow is not the site for these generic questions. If you have problems with code, go ahead and ask.

Comment: @Jeeter sorry for that i'm new here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your app just fails when they run it. Get a bigger pool of testers and see what comes up.

Comment: Could you please post some code so that we could look deeper into ur issue?

Comment: i have found that the xml and the website is down ! i will try to add a connection check to limit the process of loading ! many thanks